# SQL execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, execution

I face execution time problem here ,really upset

```
UPDATE [OT] 
SET AAA = 8 
WHERE ID in 
(
select UID from [IP] B 
inner join [OT] A 
on B.ADDR = A.ADDR and A.ID=B.ID
)  
AND AAA= 6  ;
```

OT table have duplicate ID, `count(*)` about 900000 rows
IP table have unique ID, `count(*)` about 800000 rows

AAA is a column of OT table type: `tinyint`
`select count(*) from OT where AAA=6`     about 150000

I do not know why this query will take more than 1 hour ??
My other similar query only take 10 seconds

Comment: What happens when you run the SELECT without the update? Is Addr a long string? Do you have indexes built on the joined columns?

Comment: run select still slow compare to my other query

Comment: I have same amount of data when AAA=5 and AAA=6. And if I change 6 to 5 in my query, it only take 10 s to run, I have no idea why

Comment: Ensure that you have indexes correctly defined on the join columns and get plan details from the database server, this detail may be more appropriate for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would just write this more simply as:

```
UPDATE OT
    SET AAA = 8 
    FROM OT
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM IP WHERE IP.ADDR = OT.ADDR AND IP.ID = OT.ID) AND
          OT.AAA = 6  ;
```

For performance, you want indexes on `OT(AAA)` and `IP(ADDR, ID)`.